# Can't Find Executable Path

Tags: file, path, directory, executable

I am trying to search my local machine for a certain executable. I am running mac OS.

The only way I know to find it is through the spotlight in the top right. I can find it this way, but it doesn't show me the file path.

Is there a better way to find the path leading to this executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the location of the executable through Activity Monitor. To do so:

- start the App that you are interested in (e.g. through Spotlight)
- open Activity Monitor
- select the app that you are interested in
- select the (i) icon at the top or hit ⌘-I
- select `Open Files and Ports`
- one of the first lines in that list should point you to the location of the executable that is being executed.

Comment: it wont run on my machine because it is an exec file.